# "Read More" link not displaying

Tags: read-more

I am using the [Sideshow theme](http://themeforest.net/item/sideshow-funktastic-portfolio-wordpress-theme/550344) which I received as part of a bundle hence I don't receive any support from Themezilla themselves. I am trying to insert a `"Read more"` link when I insert a `"More"` tag. I have tried following instructions from [Wordpress Codex using the_content and the_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) but haven't been able to crack it. The site I'm using it on is [onespectator.com](http://onespectator.com)

From the themes functions.php

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Change Default Excerpt Length
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tz_excerpt_length($length) {
return 55; }
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'tz_excerpt_length');

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Configure Excerpt String
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function tz_excerpt_more($excerpt) {
return str_replace('[...]', '...', $excerpt); }
add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'tz_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: Please show us some actual code, no one knows what's in a specific theme.

Comment: Hi Wyck I'm not sure which code to show. I have updated the question with code that I think could affect it but I am not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I searched for `<?php the_content(''); ?>` and changed it to `<?php the_content('Read More'); ?>` These were found in each post types php file. eg includes/video.php.

Comment: Alternatively you can add a name inside your <!--more--> tag. For instance if you wanted a "Read more" link, you would enter <!--more Read more-->